# Parse apache common log format log files

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm trying to take three pieces of information from a common log format log file. An entry of the log file would be:

```
65.54.188.137 - - [03/Oct/2007:02:20:22 -0400] "GET /~longa/statistics/code/xlispstat/smoothers/spline/ HTTP/2.0" 301 2633
```

and from that, I want to store the number of occurrences of the IP, the URLs, and the status codes in a hash. I figured they each have to be in their own. Any help would be appreciated, even if you can just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the information from the log entries with a regular expression. Something like this:

```
lines.each do |line|
  matches = /^(\S+).*GET\s(.*)\sHTTP\S*\s(\d+)/.match(line)
  ip = matches[1]
  url = matches[2]
  status = matches[3]
do
```

Then you can put this information into a hash and process it how you like.

Comment: will that regex pick up any of all three of those?

Comment: It will pick up all three, and it will *only* match if all three are present.