# Ruby Regex for Common Log Format

Tags: ruby, regex

Hey guys I'm looking for a regular expression which will 'parse' a line of the [Common Log Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) standard and will give me the 7 variables from it:

- IP
- identity
- username
- time
- request
- status
- size of the object.

Has anybody already implemented this regex?

Comment: Start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513379/parse-apache-common-log-format-log-files . It was the first result of an obvious search on a famous search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just get the time and request first, then it is just a simple split:

```
a = '127.0.0.1 user-identifier frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326'

time    = a.slice!(/\[.*?\]/)
request = a.slice!(/".*"/)
ip, identity, username, status, size = a.split
```

Comment: really simple and solves the problem, thanks @hirolau

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
127.0.0.1 user-identifier frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

**Regex:**

```
(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\[.*?\])\s+(".*?")\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)
```

Where the capture groups are numbered as in the breakdown below.

**Breakdown:**

```
Group         Regex         Match
#1 IP         (\S+)         127.0.0.1
#2 Identity   (\S+)         user-identifier
#3 Username   (\S+)         frank
#4 Time       (\[.*?\])     [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]
#5 Request    (".*?")       "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 
#6 Status     (\S+)         200
#7 Size       (\S+)         2326
each separated by a \s+
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with my own regex wich gives also splits the verb, uri and HTTP version.

```
^([\d\.]*)\s([\w|-]*)\s([\w|-]*)\s\[(.*)\]\s\"([\w]*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\"\s([\d]*)\s([\d]*)$
```