# Ignore special characters in json with python

Tags: python, json

I have an input string with special characters in my json file. The string is like

```
   "output":  "- 74.209.22x.xx - - [07/feb/2016:05:47:11 +02000] "GET /i/d_0Rn213/\22qy_1356338022.html?&rthost=rt2-c.us.net&tid=NTc1Nj0ZXSFdLNElsU3wxNDY1MjcwNjEY5T1E0VUxC123/\VVNE&ei=GOOGLE&""
```

I want it to parse as a string and ignore any special characters. I am using json.load () and I tried using `""` and `''` and `"""` ,  but i haven't been able to parse this field. How do i tell python/json module to ignore any special characters and just read it as a string ?

Comment: That's… not JSON by a long stretch…!? Please clarify why you think you'll be able to parse this with `json.load`.

Comment: its one field of json. updating example-

Comment: That's still nowhere near valid JSON. You're trying to parse *invalid JSON*, i.e. *not JSON*…?

Comment: Its just one field of the JSON file. I didn't include the brackets. The question is to just treat this field as a string literal

Comment: Looks like a web log... For example, use regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048811/ruby-regex-for-common-log-format

Comment: Since the quotes are invalid this is invalid JSON, or in other words it's not JSON and cannot be parsed as JSON. Can you fix this at the source and produce actual JSON?

Comment: It is a web log . I can escape everything manually and make it treat it as a string but is there not a way to tell JSON - just ignore the contents, treat the whole field as one string?

Comment: A web log is not typically in JSON. Are you taking a plain log file and somehow add the `"output": "…"` around it? Or what exactly is producing this "JSON" line? Because, again, you have **broken data**. It's not valid JSON. It's not a plain text line. It's neither. If you want to work with that, you need to approach the problem from the source: why *isn't* this valid JSON if it's supposed to be JSON?

Comment: What do you want at the end? A map like `{ 'output': '- 74.229...GOOGLE&"' }`

Comment: At the end, I want the whole string as it is. I ended up jsut putting \s in the quotes, please close this question.